# How to append constant array to another array using Jolt spec transformation

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following input JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "projectId": "ALL",
    "composable": "true",
    "schema": {
      "properties": {},
      "required": [ "name", "db_access" ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "projectId": "ALL",
    "composable": "true",
    "schema": {
      "properties": {},
      "required": [ "test", "remote" ]
    }
  }
]
```

Desired JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "projectId": "ALL",
    "composable": "true",
    "schema": {
      "properties": {},
      "required": [ "name", "db_access", "account", "region" ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "projectId": "ALL",
    "composable": "true",
    "schema": {
      "properties": {},
      "required": [ "test", "remote", "account", "region" ]
    }
  }
]
```

I wish to append the "account" and "region" Strings to the beginning or end (it doesn't matter) of the "required" array.
How do I achieve that using Jolt spec transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such a **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&", // attributes (or objects/arrays other than "schema"
        "schema": {
          "*": "[&2].&1.&", // attributes (or objects/arrays other than "required" 
          "required": {
            "#region|#account": "[&3].&2.&1", // [&3] : represents going three levels up the tree to get values of the indexes in array-wise manner, &2 : replicates "schema", &1 : one level up to grab "required"
            "*": "[&3].&2.&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks! That works as a charm. 
I updated my question a bit - the input/output json is now a list. Could you please update your answer to accommodate that?

Comment: I'm not sure this works as expected. I'm getting:
{
  "id" : [ "id1", "id2" ],
  "projectId" : [ "ALL", "ALL" ],
  "composable" : [ "true", "true" ],
  "schema" : {
    "properties" : [ { }, { } ],
    "required" : [ "region", "account", "name", "db_access", "region", "account", "test", "remote" ]
  }
}

Comment: It's important to see the exact picture for the Jolt. I've just edited based on the latest case @mdzh

Comment: This is better but there's still problem with the spec - the schema part is missing now. 'required' and 'properties' are directly under top level

Comment: excuse me I missed then @mdzh